# No wifi Adapter found in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, drivers

Suddenly my wifi is not working and I have tried almost everything but nothing is working for me . Here are some commands I have already tried .

1)lspci | grep Network
No result is showing and after echo $? it shows 1 .

```
I tried this method -

sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821ce
reboot
```

3)There is nothing in Additional Drivers

4)lshw -C net *-network

```
description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 0c
   serial: 84:7b:eb:2a:2c:a9
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f7000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

work

```
sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces

// interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
```

6)lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

Can anybody help me?

Comment: WiFi modules sometimes physically die. I'm not saying this has happened to you, but it looks like it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov if it did happen how can I check or resolve it?

Comment: Try booting into Windows, if it's all the same, then it's most likely dead, Jim. WiFi modules are normally replaceable, so you could simply buy something better/newer instead. Mind the form factor! Older laptops had quite weird connectors, so finding a replacement could be a challenge. Mind the host features! Some new Intel Wi-Fi module require your CPU to support some WiFi features. Don't buy Atheros for the love of God! Their WiFi modules work horribly under Linux.

Comment: Oh okay ! Thanx :)